# Alternative to query->set that appends conditions instead of overriding

Tags: wp-query

I am applying a taxonomy condition to the main query in my plugin which is excludes an array of post formats from it.

It's being done as follows:

```
$query->set('tax_query', array(
    array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'post_format',   // Post formats are queried as taxonomies
        'field'     => 'slug',
        'terms'     => self::$formats,
        'operator'  => 'NOT IN'
    )
));
```

This is working - the post formats are being excluded as I wanted them to. However the problem is that if any `tax_query` condition was specified before, then it would be overridden and lost in space and time.

Is there any way I can append my `tax_query` condition without losing overriding all conditions before it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$query->set` isn't the only method.

What you want is `$query->get`. Using `get` you can retrieve your existing value, append the additional part you wanted, then set the query variable with the new argument

```
$tax_query = $query->get( 'tax_query' );

// add the extra parameter

$query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
```

The adding the extra parameter is just appending another item using standard PHP array functionality.

Comment: Beautiful, that's exactly what I was looking for! Not sure why I didn't think of that in the first place though >.> but that's fantastic, thanks so much.